# non drawn Sprite still active xna

Tags: c#, collision-detection, draw

I am making a 2D space Shooting game and I have ran into an issue with a shield power up. The shield makes the player invincible to collision from the enemy ships for a certain amount of time. When the player collides with the power up the player is invincible for a set period of time when the player moves away from the position of the power up and the power up gets removed from the screen which all works fine. However, the issue i am having is the player can still collide with it even after it's being removed from the screen in the draw method, meaning the player could simply stay in that spot and be invincible forever. So once the player has collided with the shield, I would like it so the player cannot collide with it again. I have tried searching online but I haven't found anything that was particularly useful. 
I would also like to use this power up again. in the future I plan on adding them 'randomly' throughout my scrolling background. Not sure if this add anything to the post just thought I would include it.

game1.cs

```
    public double counterPower = 0;

    public bool powerUpCollision = false;
    public bool invincibility = false;
    Sprite shieldPower;
    bool isVisible = true; 

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
      shieldPower = new Sprite();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        if (isVisible == true)
        {
            shieldPower.LoadContent(this.Content, "powerUpShield");
            shieldPower.Position.X = 300;
            shieldPower.Position.Y = 300;
        }
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
    {
        powerUps(theGameTime);
    }

     public void powerUps (GameTime theGameTime)
    {
        if (mPlayer.boundingBox.Intersects(shieldPower.boundingBoxShieldPower)) 
        {
            if (shieldPower.isVisible == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("collision working");
                powerUpCollision = true; 
                invincibility = true;
                isVisible = false;
                if (powerUpCollision == true && invincibility == true) 
                {
                    lives = lives - 0; 
                }

                counterPower = 0;
            }
        }
        counterPower += theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counterPower);
            if (counterPower > 7) 
            {
                powerUpCollision = false;
                invincibility = false; 

            }
        }


       protected override void Draw(GameTime theGameTime)
       {
           spriteBatch.Begin();

           if (isVisible == true)
             {
                shieldPower.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
             }
       }
       spriteBatch.End();
```

In the sprite class is the bounding box for the power up, this works fine. 
I have a lot more code and classes but I'm fairly sure a lot of it isn't relevant for this issue and I also don't want to waste your time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Cant figure out how to edit the post (I'm new to Stackoverflow) but I would also like to use this power up again. in the future I plan on adding them 'randomly' throughout my scrolling background. Not sure if this add anything to the post just thought I would include it.

Comment: You can edit your post using the "edit" link below the tags (above the comments section).

Comment: Interesting syntax for C code. Mind to tell me the C-compiler for this?

Comment: "Cant figure out how to edit the post ...". Please take the [tour] first.

Comment: That tour was quite handy, my apologies. I didn't use any compilers. obviously It was meant to be c#. I added the tag for it, must have accidentally removed it when I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would first suggest is setting the bounding box to null or to somewhere it cannot possibly be collided with. It sounds like the player ship is colliding with the object because even though it isn't displayed, all of it's attributes still exist to the system. So, making it invisible and hiding it offscreen is one option, although that's for if you set the location with other code when it is supposed to be called.

Second thing, set a flag for if the powerup exists in the game. Basically nest all of your "Do this when the ship hits it" within a if statement so that it will only apply while you want it to and will skip that code when the conditions aren't met. You could actually do this instead of the first part if the bounding box wouldn't affect anything else.

edit: To clarify, something like this:

```
if(ship.hitsPowerup)
{
   if(powerup.isActive)
   {
       doTheThing;
       powerup.isActive = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I have figured it out. Thank you so much for your help. I have been stuck on it all day.

Comment: Not a problem, I have plenty of experience with the "My code doesn't work...I have no idea why" "My code works....I have no idea why" feeling hahaha

Comment: Thinking about it though it was actually not that much of a complicated fix when you think about it, just couldn't see the fix for it myself. I've spent all day on this. You have been so helpful. @Matt M